Sumar valores de dos columnas basados en dos columnas
Estoy intentando sumar valores de columnas diferentes basados en otras dos columnas que deben tener el mismo nombre.
Tengo una tabla con resultados de equipos de futbol muy básica:
+----+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+-------------+--------------+
| ID | TIME                | HOME                 | VISIT                | RESULT_HOME | RESULT_VISIT |
+----+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+-------------+--------------+
|  1 | 2024-07-22 10:00:00 | Dortmund (Lewa)      | FC Porto (Raul)      |           4 |            3 |
|  2 | 2024-07-22 10:00:00 | Barcelona (Prince)   | Arsenal (Carlos)     |           3 |            5 |
|  3 | 2024-07-22 09:45:00 | Barcelona (Prince)   | FC Porto (Raul)      |           1 |            5 |
|  4 | 2024-07-22 09:45:00 | Lazio (Mars)         | Arsenal (Carlos)     |           2 |            5 |
|  5 | 2024-07-22 09:30:00 | Lazio (Mars)         | Dortmund (Lewa)      |           2 |            4 |
|  6 | 2024-07-22 09:30:00 | FC Porto (Raul)      | Arsenal (Carlos)     |           3 |            1 |
|  7 | 2024-07-22 09:15:00 | Sporting (Professor) | Brighton (Goliath)   |           2 |            1 |
|  8 | 2024-07-22 09:15:00 | Dortmund (Lewa)      | Arsenal (Carlos)     |           5 |            3 |
|  9 | 2024-07-22 09:15:00 | Lazio (Mars)         | Barcelona (Prince)   |           4 |            6 |
| 10 | 2024-07-22 09:00:00 | Roma (Mosquito)      | Brighton (Goliath)   |           2 |            2 |
| 11 | 2024-07-22 09:00:00 | Dortmund (Lewa)      | Barcelona (Prince)   |           6 |            1 |
| 12 | 2024-07-22 09:00:00 | FC Porto (Raul)      | Lazio (Mars)         |           1 |            4 |
| 13 | 2024-07-22 08:45:00 | Roma (Mosquito)      | Bayer 04 (Arthur)    |           3 |            1 |
| 14 | 2024-07-22 08:30:00 | Sporting (Professor) | Bayer 04 (Arthur)    |           0 |            2 |
| 15 | 2024-07-22 08:30:00 | FC Porto (Raul)      | Dortmund (Lewa)      |           2 |            3 |
| 16 | 2024-07-22 08:30:00 | Arsenal (Carlos)     | Barcelona (Prince)   |           6 |            2 |
| 17 | 2024-07-22 08:15:00 | Roma (Mosquito)      | Sporting (Professor) |           0 |            2 |
| 18 | 2024-07-22 08:15:00 | Brighton (Goliath)   | Bayer 04 (Arthur)    |           1 |            5 |
| 19 | 2024-07-22 08:15:00 | Arsenal (Carlos)     | Lazio (Mars)         |           7 |            4 |
| 20 | 2024-07-22 08:15:00 | FC Porto (Raul)      | Barcelona (Prince)   |           6 |            1 |
| 21 | 2024-07-22 08:00:00 | Brighton (Goliath)   | Sporting (Professor) |           2 |            3 |
| 22 | 2024-07-22 08:00:00 | Dortmund (Lewa)      | Lazio (Mars)         |           3 |            2 |
| 23 | 2024-07-22 08:00:00 | Arsenal (Carlos)     | FC Porto (Raul)      |           2 |            4 |
| 24 | 2024-07-22 07:45:00 | Arsenal (Carlos)     | Dortmund (Lewa)      |           4 |            3 |
| 25 | 2024-07-22 07:45:00 | Barcelona (Prince)   | Lazio (Mars)         |           2 |            6 |
+----+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+-------------+--------------+

Estoy intentando encontrar los partidos hechos por cada equipo y los goles realizados con la siguiente query:
SELECT TEAM,
       sum(RESULT) AS RESULT_TOTAL,
       count(*)    AS MATCHES
FROM   (SELECT HOME        AS TEAM,
               RESULT_HOME AS RESULT
        FROM   match
        UNION
        SELECT VISIT        AS TEAM,
               RESULT_VISIT AS RESULT
        FROM   match) AS s
GROUP  BY TEAM
ORDER  BY RESULT_TOTAL DESC; 

Su resultado:
+----------------------+--------------+---------+
| TEAM                 | RESULT_TOTAL | MATCHES |
+----------------------+--------------+---------+
| Arsenal (Carlos)     |           28 |       7 |
| FC Porto (Raul)      |           21 |       6 |
| Dortmund (Lewa)      |           18 |       4 |
| Barcelona (Prince)   |           12 |       4 |
| Lazio (Mars)         |           12 |       3 |
| Bayer 04 (Arthur)    |            8 |       3 |
| Sporting (Professor) |            5 |       3 |
| Roma (Mosquito)      |            5 |       3 |
| Brighton (Goliath)   |            3 |       2 |
+----------------------+--------------+---------+

Segun el resultado, no es correcto porque, por ejemplo, "Arsenal (Carlos)" tiene 8 partidos (MATCHES) y 33 goles (RESULT_TOTAL)
|  2 | 2024-07-22 10:00:00 | Barcelona (Prince)   | Arsenal (Carlos)     |           3 |            5 |
|  4 | 2024-07-22 09:45:00 | Lazio (Mars)         | Arsenal (Carlos)     |           2 |            5 |
|  6 | 2024-07-22 09:30:00 | FC Porto (Raul)      | Arsenal (Carlos)     |           3 |            1 |
|  8 | 2024-07-22 09:15:00 | Dortmund (Lewa)      | Arsenal (Carlos)     |           5 |            3 |
| 16 | 2024-07-22 08:30:00 | Arsenal (Carlos)     | Barcelona (Prince)   |           6 |            2 |
| 19 | 2024-07-22 08:15:00 | Arsenal (Carlos)     | Lazio (Mars)         |           7 |            4 |
| 23 | 2024-07-22 08:00:00 | Arsenal (Carlos)     | FC Porto (Raul)      |           2 |            4 |
| 24 | 2024-07-22 07:45:00 | Arsenal (Carlos)     | Dortmund (Lewa)      |           4 |            3 |

Que le sucede a la Query?

El problema es que UNION elimina los duplicados, estás usando UNION en lugar de UNION ALL y en tu caso no quieres eliminar.

gracias!! era el UNION ALL
